# Altium 21 - how to configure multiple layers in schematic

Tags: schematics, altium, drc

While setting up some rules for a netclass, I wanted to prevent routing on top and bottom copper while allowing it on Inner1 and Inner2.

However, the rule dialog only has two layers available: top and bottom.

The PCB has many copper layers and I have tried back annotating but that did not seem to inform the schematic that more layers are available.

How do I get the extra layers into the net class "Routing Layers" dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the layers to your stackup in the Layer Stack Manager and save the new stackup before you can see it in the design rules.

You have this... and it's saved.
[image]
And you should be able to see this in the PCB Design Rules...
[image]

Comment: They are all in there already, that was the first thing I tried.

Comment: Yes I can see all 4 layers in the PCB rules... But I cannot see all of them in the Schematic's net class "Routing Layers" rule dialog.

Comment: Have you tried to Compile the Project?